# simple site footer in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create site footer for my wordpress site. in `HTML` I have the following:

```
<div class="footer-titles">Footer title one</div><br />
<div class="lefttext1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/html">Community</a>  <br />
<a href="http://www.subdomain.domain.com/">Forums</a>  <br />
<a href="http://www.domain.com/contact">Contact Us</a>  <br />
</div>
```

In my `CSS` I have the following:

```
.lefttext1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff; !important;
    line-height: 1.8;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: none;
    padding: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footer-titles {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.9;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

The background is `#333` and I want the font color to be `#ffffff` but I can't do that. In every time I use inspect element I see this:

```
#Bottom a {color:#888;}
#Bottom a:hover {color:#111;}
```

If this was only relevant to the home page, I would use:

```
.home #Bottom a:hover {color: #ffffff;}
.home #Bottom a:link {color: #ffffff;}
```

and that's it. But this is not the case because I want the links to be white site wide. I already tried the following code and it didn't work:

```
.lefttext1 a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff; !important;
    line-height: 1.8;
    font-weight: 400;

}
```

Please help me make the URL font color white on site wide footer as I need to override the `[#Bottom a]` on all pages for this specific pseudo selector but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any link..?

Comment: have you tried `#Bottom .lefttext1 a`?

Comment: Thanks! This worked: #Bottom .lefttext1 a { #ffffff }

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
.lefttext1 a:link, .lefttext1 a:visited, .lefttext1 a:active, .lefttext1 a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
```

}

1. a:link - a normal, unvisited link
2. a:visited - a link the user has visited
3. a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
4. a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

Comment: This didn't work: 
.lefttext1 a:link, .lefttext1 a:visited, .lefttext1 a:active, .lefttext1 a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;}

Comment: We need to add #Bottom and #Bottom a to it.

Comment: Can you please share your link